# Cakephp 2 Auth Redirect Loop

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.3

CakePhp 2 redirect loop on Web Hosting. But it working on local computer. Has anyone can solve my problem?

This is my AppController

```
class AppController extends Controller {

public $components = array(
    'Acl',
    'Auth' => array(
        'authorize' => array(
            'Actions' => array('actionPath' => 'controllers')
        ),
        'authenticate' => array(
            'Form' => array(
                'scope' => array('User.status' => '1')
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'Session',
    'DebugKit.Toolbar',
);

public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form', 'Session');

public $uses = array(
    'Configuration.Configuration',
    'EmailTemplate.EmailTemplate',
);


public $theme = "";


public function beforeFilter() {

    //Configure AuthComponent
    $this->Configuration->load();
    $this->Auth->loginAction = array(
      'controller' => 'users',
      'action' => 'login',
      'plugin' => false
    );
    $this->Auth->logoutRedirect = array(
      'controller' => 'users',
      'action' => 'login',
      'plugin' => false
    );
    $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array(
      'controller' => 'users',
      'action' => 'dashboard',
      'plugin' => false
    );

    $this->check_group();
    ####### Define Plugin layout #######
        if($this->params['plugin']=='content')
        $this->layout = 'content';

}

private function check_group()
{
    $this->theme = 'CakeReady';

    if (isset($this->request->params['admin'])) {
        $this->layout = 'admin';
    }

    if ($this->params['plugin'] == 'acl') {
        $this->layout = 'acl';
    }

    if ($this->request->is('ajax')) {
        $this->layout = 'ajax';
    }

    if(!isset($this->request->params['admin']) && Configure::read('Site.coming_soon') == 1){
        $this->theme = 'CakeReady';
        $this->layout = 'coming_soon';
        $this->set('title_for_layout', __('Coming Soon'));
    }
    else  if (!isset($this->request->params['admin']) && Configure::read('Site.status') == 0){
        $this->theme = 'CakeReady';
        $this->layout = 'maintenance';
        $this->set('title_for_layout', __('Site down for maintenance'));
    }
    else  if (!isset($this->request->params['admin'])){
        $this->theme = 'CakeReady';
        $this->layout = 'coming_soon';
        $this->set('title_for_layout', __('Coming Soon'));
    }

}
```

And its my UsersController

```
class UsersController extends AppController {
```

/**
 * Components
 *
 * @var array
 */

```
public $components = array('Paginator','Qimage');

public function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->Auth->allow('admin_forget_password', 'login', 'admin_login','subscriber','activate_code', 'register', 'captcha');
}

public function login() {
    $show_action = 'login';
    $this->layout = 'admin_login'; 
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        if ($this->Auth->login()) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Congratulation You are login succcessfully.'), 'success');
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
        }
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('<h4>Your username or password was incorrect.</h4>'), 'errorText');
    }
    $this->set(compact('show_action'));
}
```

/**
 * admin_login method
 *
 * @return void
 */

```
public function admin_login() {
    $show_action = 'login';
    $this->layout = 'admin_login';
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        if ($this->Auth->login()) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Congratulation You are login succcessfully.'), 'success');
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
        }
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('<h4>Your username or password was incorrect.</h4>'), 'errorText');
    }
    $this->set(compact('show_action'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

is mod_rewrite enabled?

You have this too?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```